# Send an email with SendGrid when i add to a new table MVC 5

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, addition, sendgrid

I want to send an email with SendGrid when i take a future student in the Registrations table and i assign him to a new Cohort, so when i add the student to the CohortsSusbcriptions table. I'm not familiar with the API call so i don't know where i have to put my action in my controller and how i make my action. This is my code:

```
        public ActionResult AddToCohort([Bind(Include = "ID,CohortId,RegistrationId,Notes,CoachId,ContractStatus,DepositStatus,PortalMemberId,ProfileImageURL,ProfileComment,PersonalityScoreD,PersonalityScoreI,PersonalityScoreS,PersonalityScoreC,EnglishProefficiencyBefore,EnglishProefficiencyAfter,SlackHandle,GraduationStatus,GitHubHandle")] CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newcohortAssignments = cohortSubscriptions;
                newcohortAssignments.ContractStatus = "Pending";
                newcohortAssignments.DepositStatus = "Pending";
                newcohortAssignments.GraduationStatus = "Not Graduated";

                db.CohortSubscriptions.Add(cohortSubscriptions);
                db.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("CohortAssignments", "Home");
            }

            ViewBag.CohortId = new SelectList(db.Cohorts, "ID", "Name", cohortSubscriptions.CohortId);

            return View(cohortSubscriptions);
        }
```

Comment: Well, the order of your actions in a controller doesn't matter. I group them when it makes to do so. However, each action I add I tend to put at end of the controller. I can say stuff about using SendGrid but you only seemed to ask about where to put the code.

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster you can say stuff about using SendGrid

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster i found the solution, i need to have a message.Subject, i have a last one quesition for you, if i have a template for the message that i sent where i put the template Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't installed SendGrid's Nuget package, install that.

Next, without a specific question about their API, I'm not sure what to say. I'll post some of my code.

Their API is a little complicated to use compared to what's in System.Net.Mail. So I wrote some code that converts System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to SendGridMessage. Then I create MailMessage objects and use my convertion code to send the email.

This is basically what I would insert into your code.

```
public ActionResult AddToCohort([Bind(Include = "ID,CohortId,RegistrationId,Notes,CoachId,ContractStatus,DepositStatus,PortalMemberId,ProfileImageURL,ProfileComment,PersonalityScoreD,PersonalityScoreI,PersonalityScoreS,PersonalityScoreC,EnglishProefficiencyBefore,EnglishProefficiencyAfter,SlackHandle,GraduationStatus,GitHubHandle")] CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newcohortAssignments = cohortSubscriptions;
        newcohortAssignments.ContractStatus = "Pending";
        newcohortAssignments.DepositStatus = "Pending";
        newcohortAssignments.GraduationStatus = "Not Graduated";

        db.CohortSubscriptions.Add(cohortSubscriptions);
        db.SaveChanges();

        using (var message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.From = new MailAddress("me@here.com");
            message.To.Add("someone@somewhere.com");
            message.Body += "Hello world!";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            MailHelper.SendMail(message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("CohortAssignments", "Home");
    }

    ViewBag.CohortId = new SelectList(db.Cohorts, "ID", "Name", cohortSubscriptions.CohortId);

    return View(cohortSubscriptions);
}
```

Following is my conversion code. It looks for your API key in Web.Config in an AppSetting named ApiKey. Oh, also it uses JetBrains.Annotations. So install that Nuget package or delete my annotations from the code.

MailHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Attachment = SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment;

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
namespace Bc3.Mail
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to send messages created with
    /// System.Net.Mail.Message through SendGrid
    /// </summary>
    [PublicAPI]
    public static class MailHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The helper function that send the MailMessage through SendGrid.
        /// It's successful when HttpStatusCode.OK or HttpStatusCode.Accepted
        /// is returned
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mail"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        [NotNull]
        public static Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string> SendMail([NotNull]MailMessage mail)
        {
            if (mail is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mail));

            var from = mail.From;
            if (from is null)
                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    "No from address");

            if (mail.To.Count == 0)
                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    "No to address");
            var to = mail.To[0];
            if (to is null)
                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    "No to address");

            SendGridMessage message;
            if (mail.To.Count == 1)
            {
                message = SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(ConvertAddress(from),
                    ConvertAddress(to),
                    mail.Subject,
                    string.Empty,
                    mail.Body);
            }
            else
            {
                var tos = from address in mail.To
                          where address is null == false
                          select ConvertAddress(address);

                message = SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(
                    ConvertAddress(from),
                    tos.ToList(),
                    mail.Subject,
                    string.Empty,
                    mail.Body);
            }

            var personalization = message?.Personalizations?[0];
            if (personalization is null)
                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error creating email message");

            if (mail.CC.Count != 0)
            {
                personalization.Ccs = new List<EmailAddress>();
                foreach (var cc in mail.CC)
                    personalization.Ccs.Add(ConvertAddress(cc));
            }
            if (mail.Bcc.Count != 0)
            {
                personalization.Bccs = new List<EmailAddress>();
                foreach (var bcc in mail.Bcc)
                    personalization.Bccs.Add(ConvertAddress(bcc));
            }

            if (mail.Attachments.Count != 0)
            {
                if (message.Attachments is null)
                    message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

                foreach (var attachment in mail.Attachments)
                {
                    if (attachment.ContentStream is null)
                        continue;

                    var sendGridAttachment = new Attachment();
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(attachment.ContentStream))
                        sendGridAttachment.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                sr.ReadToEnd()));

                    sendGridAttachment.Filename = attachment.Name;
                    sendGridAttachment.Type = attachment.ContentType.MediaType;

                    message.Attachments.Add(sendGridAttachment);
                }
            }

            if (message.Headers is null)
                message.Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var key in mail.Headers.AllKeys)
            {
                var header = mail.Headers[key];
                if (header is null)
                    continue;

                if (message.Headers.ContainsKey(header) == false)
                    message.Headers.Add(key, header);
            }

            var (httpStatusCode, errorMessage) = SendMessage(message);

            return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(httpStatusCode, errorMessage);
        }

        [NotNull]
        private static Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string> SendMessage([NotNull]SendGridMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"];
                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

                var sendTask = client.SendEmailAsync(message);
                if (sendTask is null)
                    return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Email status not received");

                sendTask.Wait();
                var response = sendTask.Result;
                if (response is null)
                    return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Email status not received");

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK
                    || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                    return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(response.StatusCode, null);

                if (response.Body is null)
                    return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(response.StatusCode, null);

                var task = response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync();
                task.Wait();

                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(response.StatusCode, task.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Message);
            }
        }
        [NotNull]
        private static EmailAddress ConvertAddress([NotNull]MailAddress address)
        {
            return new EmailAddress(address.Address, address.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the good news is that i do not have an error in your code, but no email is sent when a student is added to a cohort